# How to insert `figure` environment into the `poster` of `tcolorbox`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tcolorbox

According to the document of `tcolorbox`, we can use `blend into` option, But it can't work for me.

Error says:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/blend into', to which you passed 'figures', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \end{posterboxenv}
Not in outer par mode. \begin{figure}[H]
Undefined control sequence. \begin{figure}[H]
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{figure}[H]
```

The documents:
https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=118

following is the MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[UTF8,scheme=plain,fontset=none,10pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabu}
%\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,shapes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\RequirePackage{listings}
    \lstset{
        numbers=none,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        numbersep=5pt,
        frame=single,
        aboveskip=1mm,belowskip=1mm,
        %xleftmargin=8pt,
        language=Python,
        %alsolanguage=C++,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily \zihao{-6} \linespread{1.0} \selectfont,
        %morecomment=[l]{#},
        morekeywords={False, as, True, yield, None, assert, with, nonlocal},
        morestring=[b]",
        sensitive=true,
        %commentstyle=\kaishu \color{gray},
        %keywordstyle=\color{xsteelblue},%\bfseries,
        %stringstyle=\color{xsteelblue},
        showstringspaces=false,
        tabsize=4,
        texcl=true,
        escapechar=`
    }

\newtcolorbox{innerbox}[2]{
    left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm,
    grow to left by=2mm, grow to right by=2mm,
    sharp corners,
    breakable=true,enforce breakable,
    boxrule=0mm,
    colbacktitle={#1},
    colback={#1!10},
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\zihao{-5},
    halign title=center,
    title={#2}
}


\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
    coverage = {
        spread,
    },
    poster = {
        columns=4, rows=7,
        spacing=3mm
    },  
    boxes = {
        left=2mm, right=2mm, top=2mm, bottom=2mm,
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\zihao{5}, % 主标题
        halign title=center,        
        subtitle style={
            halign=center,
        }
    }
]


% ===================== 0. title
\begin{posterboxenv}[halign=center]{name=ptitle,below=top,span=2}
{\zihao{2} Python Cheat Sheet} \\


\leftline{demo \hfill Created By: xaero}


\end{posterboxenv}


\begin{posterboxenv}[title=Python demo, blend into=figures]{name=a1,below=ptitle}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle,rounded corners, minimum width=1mm,minimum height=1mm,text centered, draw=none,fill=none,thin]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle = 70,trapezium right angle=110,minimum width=3mm,minimum height=1mm,text centered,draw=black,fill=blue!30,thin]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle,minimum width=6mm,minimum height=3mm,text centered,text width =3mm,draw=black,fill=green!20,thin]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond,aspect=2,minimum width=1mm,minimum height=1mm,text centered,draw=black,fill=orange!30,thin]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thin,->,>=stealth,-{Stealth[length=1.2mm]}]

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
\node (start) [startstop] {};
\node (decision1) [decision,below of=start,yshift=-0.5mm] {$?$};
\node (process1a) [process,left of=decision1,yshift=-4mm,xshift=-2mm] {};
\node (stop) [startstop,below of=decision1,yshift=-5mm] {};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (decision1);
\draw [arrow] (decision1) -| node[above,font=\fontsize{4}{0}\selectfont] {$T$} (process1a);
\draw [arrow] (decision1) -- node[right,font=\fontsize{4}{0}\selectfont] {$F$} (stop);
\draw [arrow] (process1a) |- (0,-1.25) -- (stop);

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {};
\node (decision1) [decision,below of=start,yshift=-0.5mm] {$?$};
\node (process1a) [process,left of=decision1,yshift=-4mm,xshift=-2mm] {};
\node (process1b) [process,right of =decision1,yshift=-4mm,xshift=2mm] {};
\node (stop) [startstop,below of=decision1,yshift=-5mm] {};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (decision1);
\draw [arrow] (decision1) -| node[above,font=\fontsize{4}{0}\selectfont] {$T$} (process1a);
\draw [arrow] (decision1) -| node[above,font=\fontsize{4}{0}\selectfont] {$F$} (process1b);
\draw [arrow] (process1a) |- (0,-1.25) -- (stop);
\draw [arrow] (process1b) |- (0,-1.25) -- (stop);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{posterboxenv}


\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1) `blend into` is one of the initialization option keys that can only be used in the first optional argument of new box declaration commands like `\newtcolorbox`. By using `blend into`, what effect exactly do you want to achieve? Do you need a list of figures? 2) you _cannot_ use `figure` env inside `posterboxenv`. 3) Please make your example closer to "minimal", e.g., delete unused package loading and settings.

Comment: What would be the reason for the `figure` environment? Just remove `\begin{figure}[H]` and `\end{figure}` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks all! use minipage instead